# Requesting tag for AnyDice

Tags: support, tags

Many game designers and boardgame fans use Anydice as an analytics tool... There are questions regarding it specifically applied to board games. RPG SE has an anydice tag, but asking "RPG-looking, but not really" questions regarding Anydice there feels indirect.

I think we could use an `anydice` tag.

Answer (score 3):

Tags can only be created by using them in a question's tag field. You can't create them in advance. So the tag will be created when:

- someone submits a new question and adds the tag [anydice](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anydice) to it, or
- someone edits an existing question and adds the tag [anydice](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anydice) to it.

On this site, you get the [create tags privilege](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags) when you have 150 reps. With your current amount of reps, the edit would need to reviewed by a moderator or by another users who has enough reps (you need [1,000 reps to directly edit other people's contributions without review](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit)).

Comment: On board games.se, because we're a "beta" site, [our privileges have different rep progression](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) — it'll take 150 rep to be able to add a brand new tag, and 1,000 rep to edit freely without review. 2,000 is the normal amount for unreviewed editing though on non-beta sites.

Comment: @doppelgreener Thanks. I've added links to the relevant privileges in the help centre.

Comment: Looks good! 